# How to show different values inside different Modals in HTML

Tags: html, css, modal-dialog

I just want to share my code here where I got the Idea on W3schools. I already search of the same topic, but it didn't solve the problem of my Code.

```
/* The Modal (background) MY CSS CODE*/
.modal {
display: none; /* Hidden by default */
position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
left: 0;
top: 0;
width: 100%; /* Full width */
height: 100%; /* Full height */
overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* The Modal1 (background) */
.modal1 {
display: none; /* Hidden by default */
position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
left: 0;
top: 0;
width: 100%; /* Full width */
height: 100%; /* Full height */
overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}
```

And heres the Javascript Code

```
<!-- Javascript -->
<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementByclass("myModal");

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
if (event.target == modal) {
modal.style.display = "none";
}
}
</script>


<script>
// Get the modal1
var modal = document.getElementByIclass("myModal1");

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn1");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close1")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
if (event.target == modal) {
modal.style.display = "none";
}
}
</script>
```

And Lastly, the HTML Code

```
<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn">Apply Now</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div class="myModal" class="modal">

<!-- Modal content -->
<div class="modal-content">
<span class="close">&times;</span>
<p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
</div>
</div>


<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal1 -->
<button id="myBtn1">Apply Now</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div class="myModal1" class="modal1">

<!-- Modal content -->
<div class="modal-content">
<span class="close1">&times;</span>
<p>Some text in the Modalsssssss..</p>
</div>
</div>
```

I've been kinda stuck with this for a long time. Any opinion or suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**** UPDATE**

Read your comment and I agree, this is pretty "hacky" and I personally would almost never do this. So I want to show you a solution which is closer to what I would do on a production site. A quick overview:

1. The code for the actual modal is good, so we can use that.
2. What I think is "hacky" here is the way we get the data to feed to the modal. Storing data in HTML elements is not terrible, but there are way better ways to do this.
3. A good way to store this kind of data (strings, numbers, etc.) is with JSON.
4. We can include the JSON data in the document itself, or we can use AJAX to store it in a different location. Could be a file on the server, or maybe a database somewhere.

[More info on $.getJSON() method.](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/)

```js
/* Same code from previous example. New code marked with comments */
$("body").on("click", ".toggle-modal", function() {
  if ($(".modal").is(":visible")) {
    $(".modal").fadeOut("fast", function() {
      $(this).remove()
    });
  } else {

    /* Get the data ID from the html element  */
    const data_id = $(this).data("modal-text");

    /*  Get JSON data from file on server (simplified)
        Replace the url with the path to your JSON file on the server. */
    $.getJSON("https://httpbin.org/json", function(response) { // <-- Callback function

      /*  This is the "callback" function from the "getJSON" method
          This fires when the AJAX request has been completed
          This function has access to the AJAX response variable which contains the returned data */

      /* Light validation here just checks if the response is json */
      if (typeof response == 'object') {

        /* For kicks let's check out the response */
        console.log(response);

        /* The response is obviously not our data. Next variable emulates correct response */
        response = {
          primary_modal: "The message for the primary modal",
          secondary_modal: "The message for the secondary modal"
        }

        /*  Get the correct message from the response. 
            Use the value from the data attribute as the key to find our data in the json structure */
        const msg = response[data_id];

        /* Launch the modal */
        const modal = $("<div />", {
            "class": "modal"
          }).append(
            $("<div />", {
              "class": "modal-overlay toggle-modal"
            }),
            $("<div />", {
              "class": "modal-container"
            }).append(
              $("<div />", {
                "class": "modal-close toggle-modal"
              }),
              $("<div />", {
                "class": "modal-content"
              }).text(msg) // <-- The message
            )
          ).appendTo("body")
          .fadeIn("fast")
          .css("display", "flex");
      } else {
        return "Couldn't get the data";
      }

    });
  }
})
```

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: cyan;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 9000;
  padding: 20px;
}

.modal-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-container {
  background: white;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: normal;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  z-index: 20;
}

.modal-close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 8px 20px;
  background: coral;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.modal-close:before {
  content: "X"
}

.modal-content {
  padding: 35px 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<!-- We removed the modal data and added a reference to the data in the json -->

<div>
  <button class="toggle-modal" data-modal-text="primary_modal">Click Here</button>

  <button class="toggle-modal" data-modal-text="secondary_modal">Click Here</button>
</div>
```

Here is a really easy way to re-purpose a modal template for different content using jQuery. Basically you store the message right in the button's data attribute, then just append that content to the dynamically generated modal.

```js
/* Listen for the click event on the button */
$("body").on("click", ".toggle-modal", function() {
  /* Check if modal is open */
  if ($(".modal").is(":visible")) {
    /* if modal is already visible close it out */
    $(".modal").fadeOut("fast", function() {
      $(this).remove()
    });
  } else {
    /* Get message from button */
    const msg = $(this).data("modal-text");

    /* dynamically create modal elements */
    const modal = $("<div />", {
        "class": "modal"
      }).append(
        $("<div />", {
          "class": "modal-overlay toggle-modal"
        }),
        $("<div />", {
          "class": "modal-container"
        }).append(
          $("<div />", {
            "class": "modal-close toggle-modal"
          }),
          $("<div />", {
            "class": "modal-content"
          }).text(msg) /* Append text to modal */
        )
      ).appendTo("body") /* Append modal to body */
      .fadeIn("fast") /* Fade in modal */
      .css("display", "flex") /* Flexbox to center content */
  }

})
```

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: cyan;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 9000;
  padding: 20px;
}

.modal-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-container {
  background: white;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: normal;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  z-index: 20;
}

.modal-close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  font-family:sans-serif;
  font-size:14px;
  line-height:1;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 8px 20px;
  background: coral;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.modal-close:before {
  content: "X"
}

.modal-content {
  padding: 35px 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<!-- Set the modal text right in the data attribute of the button. This approach works for short messages but may not be well suited for more complex content -->

<div>
  <button class="toggle-modal" data-modal-text="Short message to be displayed in the first modal">Click Here</button>

  <button class="toggle-modal" data-modal-text="A different message for the secondary modal">Click Here</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! this solution works like an ez hack! we really appreciate this.

Comment: Hooked you up with an extended answer.